# MySQL statement to return 2 students

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I want a SQL statement that would  return all courses 
having at least 2 students enrolled which is ordered by course with the 
greatest number of students. I am pretty new with SQL stuff and I am finding it bit difficult.

here is my current database

```
 CREATE TABLE `course` (
      `CourseID` char(11) NOT NULL,
      `Course_name` varchar(22) DEFAULT NULL,
      `hours_per_week` varchar(22) DEFAULT NULL,
      `Start_date` date DEFAULT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

    --
    -- Dumping data for table `course`
    --

    INSERT INTO `course` (`CourseID`, `Course_name`, `hours_per_week`, `Start_date`) VALUES
    ('C001', 'Cert 1', '15', '2012-02-01'),
    ('C002', 'Cert 2', '20', '2012-02-02'),
    ('C003', 'Cert 3', '16', '2012-02-03'),
    ('C004', 'Cert 4', '20', '2012-02-13');

    -- --------------------------------------------------------

    --
    -- Table structure for table `enrolment`
    --

    CREATE TABLE `enrolment` (
      `studentID` char(11) NOT NULL,
      `courseID` char(11) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

    --
    -- Dumping data for table `enrolment`
    --

    INSERT INTO `enrolment` (`studentID`, `courseID`) VALUES
    ('S001', 'C001'),
    ('S002', ' C001'),
    ('S003', ' C002'),
    ('S004', ' C002'),
    ('S005', ' C004');

    -- --------------------------------------------------------

    --
    -- Table structure for table `student`
    --

    CREATE TABLE `student` (
      `StudentID` char(11) NOT NULL,
      `FirstName` varchar(22) DEFAULT NULL,
      `LastName` varchar(22) DEFAULT NULL,
      `DOB` date DEFAULT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

    --
    -- Dumping data for table `student`
    --

    INSERT INTO `student` (`StudentID`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `DOB`) VALUES
    ('S001', 'Alison', 'Tildesley', '1984-05-09'),
    ('S002', 'Fred', 'Nile', '1940-03-03'),
    ('S003', 'Christine', 'Anu', '1970-09-01'),
    ('S004', 'Jame', 'Brown', '1976-02-03'),
    ('S005', 'Mark', 'Oliphant', '1958-03-10'),
    ('S006', 'George', 'Bush', '1951-11-28');
```

This is what I have tried

```
SELECT FROM COURSES WHERE STUDENT_ID >=2
```

I know I have to add `student_id` row into my course table but I am still confused how to get desired results.  I am sorry I am very new to database and MYSQL statements.

Comment: Great start. Can you show us the expected result as well, having that table data. And your current query attempt.

Comment: Also... what we will get back for doing your homework? Will you assign us your mark?

Comment: added what I have tried but still pretty newbie with SQL and I have to complete it :/

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
SELECT C.CourseID, C.Course_name, COUNT(E.StudentID) Students_num
FROM course C
JOIN enrolment E USING(CourseID)
GROUP BY C.CourseID, C.Course_name
HAVING Students_num >= 2
ORDER BY Students_num DESC, C.Course_name
```

This will extract all courses joined with their enrollment records, and then group them by the course ID and name, counting the number of students; the last `HAVING` clause will discard all records that, after the grouping, will have less than 2 students.

Here is a [working SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fc940/8) for testing.

Comment: Hi Matteo thank you very much. can you tell me what c.? like C.CourseID and C.Course_name?

Comment: `C` is just the alias I chose for the `course` table, in the line `FROM course C`; I really recommend you read up some documentation about mysql syntax at http://dev.mysql.com/

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'HAVING Students_num >= 2 LIMIT 0, 25' at line 6

i got this when I run this query

Answer (score 0):

Not tested ;)

```
select 
    c.courseID, count(0)
from course c, enrolment e 
where c.CourseID = e.CourseID
group by 
    c.courseID
having
    count(0) >= 2
order by 
    count(0) desc
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you five : )

Comment: would it return all courses having at least 2 students enrolled "which is ordered by course with the greatest number of students"? thanks

Comment: i think yes, not sure. doesnt got mysql in my compute.